# Display PHP error on same page of form?

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have two files my first one is the form itself

Here's the form `index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/s/r.php" >
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="pass1"><br>
Password, again: <input type="text" name="pass2"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And then my `r.php`

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass1']);
$pass2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass2']);

// Verification

if (empty($name) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($pass1) || empty($pass2))
    {
    echo "Complete all fields";

    // you can stop it here instead of putting the curly brace ALL the way at the bottom :)

    return;
    }

// Password match

if ($pass1 <> $pass2)
    {
    echo $passmatch = "Passwords don't match";
    }

// Email validation

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    echo $emailvalid = "Enter a  valid email";
    }

// Password length

if (strlen($pass1) <= 6)
    {
    echo $passlength = "Password must be at least 6 characters long";
    }

// Password numbers

if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $pass1))
    {
    echo $passnum = "Password must include at least one number!";
    }

// Password letters

if (!preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $pass1))
    {
    echo $passletter = "Password must include at least one letter!";
    }

?>
```

And I also have my `db.php` which isn't relevant to the issue. So I'm trying to make the form not go to `r.php` and display the errors if there is an error, but rather make it display next to the form, in `index.php`. Is there a way to prevent it from going to `r.php` or would I have to combine the two scripts?

Comment: Make `index.php` include `r.php` and do the auth there. the other way is to redirect back to `index.phph` with the error massage as a parameter.

Comment: A more detailed example please? @MichaelCoxon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply put your `r.php` code in `index.php` and then change the form action, just put it as `action=""` instead of `action="http://localhost/s/r.php"`
To prevent auto executing the php code, you could use `isset`.

change your input button as follow

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(!empty($name)){echo $name;}?>"><br>
Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(!empty($username){echo $username;}"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(!empty($email)){echo $email;}?>"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="pass1" value="<?php if(!empty($pass1)){echo $pass1;}?>"><br>
Password, again: <input type="text" name="pass2" value="<?php if(!empty($pass2)){echo $pass2;}?>"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

then put your php code inside this.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//put the php code here.
}
?>
```

Comment: It works good. But here are a few questions. Could I just get rid of the `action` and just use `method`? And how would I have the input stay when the user submits invalid data? So that then they wouldn't have to retype it?

Comment: You could get rid of it but I would leave it as `action=""` cos it's valid html. See my edit, just do the same thing for the last two.

Comment: You probably want to add the `?>` but now I get this when I try it `<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: name in <b>/Users/idrisk/Colourity/s/index.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />` inside the inputs when I submit invalid info

Comment: Nevermind. I just had to place the HTML at the bottom of the file.

Comment: yeah I forgot the closing tags, also I edited my answer. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could you javascript validation or can make both html & php in the same page to show the error.

Comment: Javascript could be removed.

Comment: JS validation should only be used as client-side 'niceness'

Comment: yes, thats the negattive point of using client side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass your error message as an HTTP post or get variable to `index.php`.

Everywhere you're currently `echo`ing errors now, instead set an `$error` variable,
then you can add something like

```
if ($error) {
   header("index.php?error=" + $error); // passing error(s) as an HTTP get variable via the querystring
}
```

Then in `index.php` you can process the `error` query variable.

Comment: So for my `r.php` it would look like this? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b7669ef01bd6d0fefbda And my `index.php` would look like this? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63e69632b43f9dc4519a

Comment: Close. In `index.php` the conditional should be `if ($_GET["name"])`.
I would instead have just one `$error` variable and append it with any error messages (since you could have multiple errors), then do the redirect as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" >
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="pass1"><br>
Password, again: <input type="text" name="pass2"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
  {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass1']);
    $pass2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass2']);

    // Verification

    if (empty($name) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($pass1) ||         empty($pass2))
        {
        echo "Complete all fields";

        // you can stop it here instead of putting the curly brace ALL the way at the bottom :)

        return;
        }

    // Password match

    if ($pass1 <> $pass2)
        {
        echo $passmatch = "Passwords don't match";
        }

    // Email validation

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
        echo $emailvalid = "Enter a  valid email";        
        }

    // Password length

    if (strlen($pass1) <= 6)
        {
        echo $passlength = "Password must be at least 6 characters long";
        }

    // Password numbers

    if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $pass1))
        {
        echo $passnum = "Password must include at least one number!";
        }

    // Password letters

    if (!preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $pass1))
        {
        echo $passletter = "Password must include at least one letter!";
        }
  }       
 ?>
```

Comment: No php tags in the file?

Answer (score 0):

you could use XHR (ajax) using javascript to send the form without leaving the page.
you would use the onsubmit event of the form (returning false to prevent default behaviour) or onclick event of a button. you would update your form in the callback:

```
var x=(window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
x.onreadystatechange=function(){if(x.readyState==4&&x.status==200){
alert(x.responseText); //update your form
}}
x.open('GET','r.php',true);x.send();
```

you could send a javascript from your php as well, append a script element to the body of the document and set its innerHTML (or innerText)